# Retriving child nodes in the Content tree from another Hive provider

Tags: umbraco

Having read around it appears this should be possible. I have the following content tree:

- Home Page

  - Cars
    -- List Of Cars (From my Hive provider).

I assumed I would be able to do something like this in my provider Uri:

```
content://*/Cars/*
```

as described in an Umbraco blog post (http://jupiter.umbraco.org/Data-Access-in-Umbraco-5.ashx). However it appears Umbraco does not accept this as an Uri. Also the blog post specified use of Type="Wildcard" on the mapping, however this is no longer in Umbraco??

Does anyone have an example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umbraco 5 does not yet support this.

Comment: Hi James, is that slated for > 5.1 release? I've been trying to find where they discuss this. I found a method GetEntityByRoute mentioned on the wiki but it hasn't been implemented yet.